# Umbraco 7: Get all siblings from current page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Content.Children.Where("Visible"))
            {
                <a title="@item.Name" href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a>
            }
```

This does not give the result I need. 
**Q:** How can I get all the all siblings pages from current page?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
@var siblings = Model.Content.Siblings()

@foreach (var item in siblings.Where(x => x.Id != Model.Content.Id))
{
    <a title="@item.Name" href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a>
}
```

Comment: Thanks! how can I get all siblings except current page?

Comment: Kind of strange that siblings would include itself!

Comment: I guess it depends on how you look at it. I assumed the same as you, but it could also mean "the siblings" as opposed to the content's siblings. Having said that, there is already `.Ancestors()` and `.AncestorsOrSelf()` so maybe it should be `.Siblings()` and `.SiblingsOrSelf()`?